# Удаление пустых элементов из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Как удалить элементы с пустым значением

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'team' => string 'Home'
      'town' => string 'Moscow'
      'home_scorers' => string 'player_1, player_2'
      'away_scorers' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'team' => string 'Away'
      'town' => string 'St.Peterburg'
      'home_scorers' => null
      'away_scorers' => string 'player_1'
```

Так я пытаюсь парсить url

```
$html = file_get_html('http://some_url');
foreach($html->find('div[class="about-command"]') as $element) {
 $item['team'] = $element->find('h2[class="titleH2"]', 0)->plaintext;
 $item['town'] = $element->find('div[class="town"]', 0)->plaintext;
 $item['home_scorers'] = $element->find('div[class="js-first-team"]', 0)->plaintext;
 $item['away_scorers'] = $element->find('div[class="js-second-team"]', 0)->plaintext;
 $elements[] = $item;
}
```

Получается массив представленный выше. Вот пустые элементы и хочу удалить.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: Интересно, а зачем удалять элементы в структурированном массиве? Будет лишний цикл для удаления пустых элементов, а проверку вам при выводе все равно использовать, только теперь вместо проверки на `null` (или пустая строка) вам нужен будет `isset()`

Comment: Если окажется, что все элементы подмассива `null` – сам подмассив надо же удалить?  И структура только такого вида может быть, или глубже?

Comment: @Sergiks глубже не будет, отредактировал вопрос, описал что хочу сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После обновления вопроса стало ясно, что лучше изменить процесс наполнения массива, чем пробегать его ещё раз и чистить массивы от пустых значений:

```
// ф-я, чтобы дважды длинные строки значения не писать
function addNonEmptyValue( &$arr, $key, $value) {
    if( !is_null($value)) $arr[$key] = $value;
}

$html = file_get_html('http://some_url');
foreach($html->find('div[class="about-command"]') as $element) {
    $item = array();
    addNonEmptyValue( $item, 'team'         , $element->find('h2[class="titleH2"]', 0)->plaintext);
    addNonEmptyValue( $item, 'town'         , $element->find('div[class="town"]', 0)->plaintext);
    addNonEmptyValue( $item, 'home_scorers', $element->find('div[class="js-first-team"]', 0)->plaintext);
    addNonEmptyValue( $item, 'away_scorers', $element->find('div[class="js-second-team"]', 0)->plaintext);
    $elements[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо! только начинаю разбираться в php, но уже понял, что главная проблема в построении логики при написании кода, что подскажете?) Ещё не сразу заметил вот что 'away_scorers' => boolean false. Почему так получилось?

Comment: Вероятно, метод `find()` возвращает Булево значение (`true` или `false`), которое методом `plaintext()` преобразуется буквально к указанной строке.

Comment: Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1):

В таком массиве - только с помощью цикла.

```
foreach ($array as $idx=>$subarray) {
 foreach ($subarray as $name=>$item {
  if ($item === null) {
   //если требуется более широкое определение, то !$item
   //или empty($item)
   unset ($array[$idx][$name]);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: добавить, может, `if( !count($subarray)) unset( $array[$idx]);` после `if{..}` ?

Comment: В рамках данной задачи  это излишне. И вообще, лучше не "напрягать" count для проверок, а использовать empty(). Так как  empty не является функцией, то работает быстрее.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `array_filter()` в цикле и будем Вам счастье :)

```
for($i=0; $i<Count($array); $i++) {
    $array[$i] = array_filter($array[$i], 'cleanEmptyElements');
}

function cleanEmptyElements($arrayItem) {
    return (strlen($arrayItem));
}
```

В результате получаем

```
array(2) {
  array(3) {
    ["team"]=>
    string(4) "Home"
    ["town"]=>
    string(6) "Moscow"
    ["home_scorers"]=>
    string(18) "player_1, player_2"
  },
  array(3) {
    ["team"]=>
    string(4) "Away"
    ["town"]=>
    string(12) "St.Peterburg"
    ["away_scorers"]=>
    string(8) "player_1"
  }
}
```

Comment: А если будет не только строка, но и число? А если пустая строка?

Comment: ну это уже по заданию.... здесь все строки. Но для универсальности надо менять `(strlen($arrayItem))` на другие проверки: `is_null`, `is_object` ну по желанию :)

Comment: кстати, я проверил, если `integer` или `""` внесено - все равно `strlen` правильно отрабатывает... ;)

Comment: да, действительно